# Normal distribution random variable probability

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The daily exchange rates for the five-year period **2003** to **2008** between the euro (EUR) and the British pound (GBP) are well-modeled by a normal distribution with mean **1.459** euros (to pounds), and standard deviation **0.033** euros. What is the probability that on a randomly selected day during this period, the pound was worth (1) less than **1.459** euros, (2) more than **1.492** euros

When trying to solve this, I did:

1) **z=(1.495-1.495)/0.033** and then matched the answer of **0** with **z<0** on the standard normal probabilities table to get **0.5**, which is correct.

2)**(1.492-1.495)/0.033** and got the answer **0.0909**, with which I matched it with **0.09** on the table and got **0.4641**, but the correct answer is **0.1587** and I am confused about how to get this answer.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Let $X$ be the random variable of the exchange rate. In the second question, you are looking for $P(X \geq 1.492) = 1 - P(X \leq 1.492)$. Did you remember to do this step (subtract from 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the random variable $X=$The price of the pound in euros on a randomly selected day within this period.

Then

$$X\sim N\left(1.459,0.033^2\right)$$
$$P(X \ge 1.492)=P\left(\cfrac{1.459 - 99}{0.033} \le X \le \cfrac{1.459-1.492}{0.033}\right)=P(-2955 \le z \le -1)=\color{red}{\fbox{0.158655253}}$$
as required.

If you are wondering where the $99$ came from I simply selected an arbitrarily large value to ensure all values of $X$ were covered up to $X=1.492$.

As you are using tables you can simply select a very large and negative $z$ value.

Comment: thank you very much for the help! I understand now.

Comment: I just have one question, I thought that in order to find the z-score you must input the values into the formula z=(x-μ)/σ... why is it not (1.492-1.459)/0.033? Once again, thank you for the help.

Comment: @Astag Yes the formula is $\cfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ but switching the order of $x$ and $\sigma$ only changes the sign, so the way I have done it will still give the correct answer

Comment: Oh okay, I just thought that the final answer would vary based on the sign.

Comment: @Astag You're right, the answer is based on the sign, but because I switched the order on both sides of the inequality the answer will still be correct. Try switching the order to $x-\mu$ and you should get $-0.158655213$

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, it is much appreciated.